# How to adjust the scrollbar thumb height?

Tags: html, css

i have a container which has a scrollbar. i want two things 1. adjust the height and hide the over flow.

i tried so many things from internet nothing worked. below the css i have used

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything below the module 2 div?

Comment: For vertical scroll-bars, the height of the thumb is directly related to the amount of the total content shown in the viewport. That is to say, if you have 100 pixels of content and 50 pixels of viewport, the thumb will be 50 pixels high. Resizing this would not make sense.. It's the exact same situation with the thumb-width for horizontal scrollers. They provide both a controll to manipulate the window and feedback about the current state.

Comment: Thanks , i understood the concept. Did you know how manage the scrollbar thumb overflow the one i marked red.

Comment: You're welcome. The part of your image in the red-circle looks to me like a non-customizable part. That is to say - we can see the top of a container. We can also see the thumb at the top of it's track. Each of these tell me there's a scrollable container that is scrolled all the way to the top. (That means everything is working as designed and *more importantly* as people expect. Fewer programs are 'skinned' now than used to be, since people came to expect and rely on standards)

I almost certain that I don't understand what you're asking me, sorry.
Could you ask with different words?